# Garbage collector and non-disposable types

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, .net-6.0

Give the following code:

```
public static void Test() {
    new Timer((x)=> {
       Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
}
public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
   Test();
   await Task.Delay(10000);
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   GC.Collect();
   await Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExitAsync();
}
```

Once the `GC.Collect()` hits, we can see that the `Timer` is collected and it stops working since it implement `IDisposable`. But if I replace the `Timer` with a `Task`, let's say:

```
public static void Test() {
    Task.Run(async () => {
        while(true) {
           Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
           await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    });
}
```

We can see that the `Task` keeps running although it's reference is not kept. But we know that `Task` does not implement `IDisposable`.

In both these methods I intentionally wrote a bad code for testing purpose and I did not assign the references of `Timer` and `Task` to any variables so that they would fall into the first generation (in garbage collection).

Since `Task` keeps running, here's a few related questions:

1- Will it be collected by Garbage Collector some time in the future?

2- Does the Garbage Collector allows the `Task` to run as long as the OS does not run short in memory?

I ran some test and I saw that the `Task` actually keeps running even for hours, but I need to know if this behavior is guaranteed to continue.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think this question needs you sir!

Comment: GC does nothing with `IDisposable`, it even does not know anything about this. The `Task` is definitely stored internaly inside `ThreadPool/BCL` to be sheduled/executed, so it will not GC-ed until it's completion. As for `Timer` - I'm unsure which exactly timer is used here and how it is implemented internally. May be it is really has no managed references anywhere and is GC-ed.

Comment: @Serg: If we replace the `Timer` with any other type that implements `IDisposable` we see the once the `GC.Collect` hits, the finalizer is hit too. The finalizer here being the old C++ destructor, meaning all types must come with a default one, when a type is not `IDisposable` it stays there in the memory. So when will they be collected? Will they be collected at all?

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder Like Serg says, it has nothing to do with IDisposable. It is all about who has a reference to it. The task is referenced by the threadpool.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: In that case how is the lifecyle of the `Task` managed? does it run forever?

Comment: It runs until it's complete or throws an exception. *Why* do you think it would have a lifetime influenced by the GC?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Because I created a task whose reference I didn't keep, that is why I am asking the question.

Comment: a `Task` object represents *some activity that may complete in the future*. Some tasks are associated with activity that has been scheduled on the thread pool (such as via `Task.Run`). Others are associated with a `TaskCompletionSource`. (And still others represent async method calls) Note though that, in either case, whether you hold onto the `Task` object is *irrelevant* to the activity that is going to complete in the future.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes that is exactly what I need to know, does the garbage collector collect the Task some time in the future before it completes?

Comment: *Even if the `Task` is collected*, that doesn't affect the *ongoing activity*. That's what I'm trying to make you see is a *separate* thing.

Comment: Yes, until it's eligible to be (garbage) collected.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: That's very interesting. Would you please explain that in a bit more details?

Comment: No, GC will not collect the task until it is not run to completion or is failed, as before this happened, the reference to the task is stored inside the BCL. But this is implementation details and you actually should not rely on it. Anyway, I beleive GC can't stop/kill ongoing task execution (except the case of application shutdown).

Comment: Also you should really use `GC.Collect(2);` to fully test GC capability

Comment: I would note that Task *do* implement IDisposable, but as far as I can see does not have a finalizer. See also [Do I need to dispose tasks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `System.Threading.Timer` timer is designed to be stopped on garbage collection. Because you do not assign the timer object to any variable, it goes out of scope immediately. There are no references to the timer object (whether in your code, nor somewhere else). Therefore, it is eligible to garbage collection.

See https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs for the implementation. The `Timer` class creates a `TimerHolder` object internally. `TimerHolder` itself has a finalizer (`~TimerHolder`) which finally "*closes*" the timer once the GC runs the finalizer.

Be aware, that GC is not deterministic, in other scenarios the timer maybe will run longer (depending on how long your object has already been referenced, it may be moved to higher GC generations).

---

The `Task` class, respectively the entire asynchronous programming API is much more complex than it seems in the first place. There is a lot of work and plumbing happening in the background. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async.

A `Task` is typically handled by a `TaskScheduler`, which is associated with your current thread and usually also with other threads. Therefore, a reference to the task object exists somewhere, which prevents the task from being garbage-collected. At least until the task is completed. This is a very simplified explanation.

---

Edit (after some more research):

A task created using `Task.Delay` is not handled by the `TaskScheduler` (the task itself has no active work, it is just waiting, so it would make no sense to schedule it).

`Task.Delay` internally also uses `System.Threading.Timers`. But the  timer is explicitly kept running, by simply suppressing finalization using `GC.SuppressFinalize` on the internal `TimerHolder` object.

see https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs

---

As you may notice, this has nothing to do with implementation of IDisposable.